# Centering part name in book

Tags: table-of-contents, books, parts

How can I center the part name in the TOC ?

I want the TOC to print :

> ```
>                                  Partie I - First part
> ```
>
> Chapitre 1 - First chapter
>
> Chapitre 2 - Second one

Instead I have :

> Partie I - First part
>
> Chapitre 1 - First chapter
>
> Chapitre 2 - Second one

Here is a minimal code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

% Part name in TOC
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\centering}
\renewcommand\cftpartleader{}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{part}}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{ Partie \Roman{part} --\hspace{-.4cm}}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapitre\ }
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{\hfill--\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{3.2cm}
\renewcommand\cftdotsep{2}
%\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} %Si on veut mettre des pointillés
%\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\newcommand\Bpart[1]{\part{\texorpdfstring{}{}#1}}
\newcommand\Bchapter[1]{\chapter{\texorpdfstring{}{Chapitre \arabic{chapter} -- }#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}

\end{document}
```

In fact I don't konow at all how to center the part name so I tried a desperate `centering` without success.

How can I fix it ?

Thank you.

Comment: What about the part page number?

Comment: I don't want the page number for the part in TOC ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with

```
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfil}
\renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfil}
```

**complete code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

% Part name in TOC
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfil}
\renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfil}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{part}}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{ Partie \Roman{part} --\hspace{-.4cm}}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapitre\ }
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{\hfill--\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{3.2cm}
\renewcommand\cftdotsep{2}
%\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} %Si on veut mettre des pointillés
%\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\newcommand\Bpart[1]{\part{\texorpdfstring{}{}#1}}
\newcommand\Bchapter[1]{\chapter{\texorpdfstring{}{Chapitre \arabic{chapter} -- }#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]